# Clickable links in terminal output

Tags: python, python-3.x, hyperlink, pycharm

My python program outputs a set of url links. When I run this on pycharm, I can directly click on the links and that will open them up in the browser. However, when I run the python file by double clicking on the .py file, the links are not clickable. I want the links to be clickable so it takes me to the browser directly. 
Please support solutions with explanations as I am still learning. Thanks!

Comment: This is an issue of the terminal, **not** of Python. Evidently PyCharm's terminal supports clickable URLs but your system terminal doesn't.

Comment: Please give more information about your operating system and terminal and it is possible to suggest a solution

Comment: Is it possible to add links to iTerm2 on MacOS X?

Comment: Maybe you have better luck with stripping `http://` or `https://` from the URL. CTRL + click will open the link in some terminals.

Answer (score 1):

As outlined above, you need to use a terminal that supports clicking of URL's.

On linux, most terminals do this. Ex Gnome-terminal, terminator etc.. 
On Mac, try iterm2.