# How to make file paths in console output of pytest clickable in PyCharm terminal?

Tags: terminal, hyperlink, pycharm, pytest, pytest-cov

If I run `pytest --cov` in a PyCharm terminal, I get output like

```
FAIL Required test coverage of 100.0% not reached. Total coverage: 55.03%
=========================================================================================================================================== short test summary info =========================================================================================================================================== 
FAILED test/fhg_isi/plotting/test_matplotlib.py::test_create_graph - TypeError: create_graph() missing 1 required positional argument: 'template'
FAILED test/fhg_isi/plotting/test_matplotlib.py::test_create_graph_having_subplots - TypeError: create_graph_having_subplots() missing 1 required positional argument: 'template'
```

=> How can I make the file paths clickable to be able to easily open the files in PyCharm?

Is there a specific type of coverage report I should use or some hidden PyCharm console setting etc.?

Related:

[Clickable links in terminal output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30026870/clickable-links-in-terminal-output)

https://www.reddit.com/r/pycharm/comments/oh5xzj/how_can_i_make_line_code_links_clickable_from_the/

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154439/Terminal-toolwindow-should-linkify-references-to-project-sources